# shopify liquid templates list of all assigned variables similar to smarty

Tags: debugging, liquid

I wonder is there some tool similar to Debug tag in smarty to show all assigned variables in liquid templates. I am new to liquid and for me developing is going pretty much in "blind mode" - I can't use debugger in templates because it's not ruby and I don't know how to list all variables to see whats going on.

So, if anybody know such a tool, or command to list all variables - please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I actually solved my problem by myself - I wrote a little plugin for to inspect environment variables in a webtools console. If anyone interested - take a look [here](https://github.com/sandric/octopress-inspector)

Comment: Sorry, new to ruby, liquid and shopify. How would you include it in your code? I mean it's fine to say {% inspect %}, but how would liquid know where to find the inspect code?

Comment: I appreciate you posting this. I am using it right now to troubleshoot a problem where a variable in the template isn't getting populated. Using your tool, I can see clearly that Liquid knows about the variable, but it still isn't publishing on the first hit to the page. However, an immediate refresh rectifies the issue, and other variable ARE being populated. Any idea?